# Erro android studio 2.2 osx

Tags: android-studio

Recentemente instalei o android studio 2.1.1 no meu mac. Realizei todas as configurações necessárias, só que quando inicio o AVD ele retorna este erro:

> emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB emulator: WARNING: VM
>   heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 48MB emulator:
>   WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB Hax is enabled Hax ram_size
>   0x40000000 HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. console
>   on port 5554, ADB on port 5555

e na aba APP este:

> Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for
>   emulator to come online.

Como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Este erro é devido à quantidade de memória que você setou no device que você esta emulando. Está sendo sugerida na mensagem setar para 1024Mb.

Para fazer isso, use o AVD Manager e configure a mmemória do device. Essas configurações no AVD estão em Avdanced Settings do device.